# Why is my code displaying unmoving circles?

Tags: methods, processing, draw

So here's my code, pretty simple stuff:

```java
void setup(){
size(200,200);
background(255);
}

void draw(){
  ac();
}
void ac(){ 
  int xPos = 10;
  int yPos = 20;
  int sizeXY = 40;
  int xInt = 10;
  int yInt = 20;
  int[] xM = new int[5];
  int[] yM = new int[5];
  for(int x:xM){
   xM[x] = xPos;
   xPos += xInt;
  }
  for(int y:yM){
   yM[y] = yPos;
   yPos += yInt;
  }
  for(int z = 0;z<5;z++){
   ellipse(xM[z],yM[z],sizeXY,sizeXY); 
  }
}
```

However when I test it out I only get 2 unmoving circles, one in the upper left and one in the centre. What may be causing this and how can I fix it so that circles are created next to each other with X and Y axes increasing gradually with the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Variables that you define inside a function are only **in scope** inside that function. When the function ends, those variables go out of scope and no longer exist. Next time you run the function, you recreate the variables with the same value, which is why you don't see any movement.

I'm also a little confused about what you're trying to do: why do you have `xPos` and a `yPos` variables, as well as `xM` and `yM` variables? What do you intend each to be used for? If you want to show a bunch of moving circles, my guess is you can probably get rid of `xPos` and `yPos` and only use the arrays.

Also, this `for` loop is not doing what you expected:

```
for(int x:xM){
  xM[x] = xPos;
  xPos += xInt;
}
```

Here you're looping over the values in `xM` but then using them as indexes. You probably just want to do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < xM.length; i++){
  xM[i] += xInt;
}
```

Notice that I've gotten rid of the `xPos` variable because I don't think you need it. The same problem is happening in your second `for` loop as well.

I suggest you take a step back and start with something simpler. Use arrays that hold a single value, and then treat it like you would any other variable using the `0` index, e.g. `xM[0] += xInt`. Get it working for one circle first. Then add a second circle and try to add the `for` loops. Work forward in small steps instead of trying to take everything on all at once. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

I think, you can achieve your aim by defining xPos and yPos as global variables and by setting them only once to 10 or 20 in the setup-function.

So your Code could look like this:

```
int xPos;
int yPos;

void setup(){
size(200,200);
background(255);
xPos=10;
yPos=20;
}

void draw(){
  ac();
}
void ac(){ 
  //int xPos = 10;
  //int yPos = 20;
  int sizeXY = 40;
  int xInt = 10;
  int yInt = 20;
  int[] xM = new int[5];
  int[] yM = new int[5];
  for(int x:xM){
   xM[x] = xPos;
   xPos += xInt;
  }
  for(int y:yM){
   yM[y] = yPos;
   yPos += yInt;
  }
  for(int z = 0;z<5;z++){
   ellipse(xM[z],yM[z],sizeXY,sizeXY); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't run it and I'm sorry, that it doesn't work. But what I want to show with this code is, that there has to be some **variable in the code, that changes from loop to loop.** I hope that helps...

Answer (score -1):

You can change the way you define and work with your *for* loops:

```
void setup(){
size(200,200);
background(255);
}

void draw(){
  ac();
}
void ac(){ 
  int xPos = 10;
  int yPos = 20;
  int sizeXY = 40;
  int xInt = 10;
  int yInt = 20;
  int[] xM = new int[5];
  int[] yM = new int[5];
  for(int z = 0;z<xM.length;z++){
   xM[z] = xPos;
   xPos += xInt;
  }
  for(int z = 0;z<yM.length;z++){
   yM[z] = yPos;
   yPos += yInt;
  }
  for(int z = 0;z<5;z++){
   ellipse(xM[z],yM[z],sizeXY,sizeXY); 
  }
}
```